# How send string parameter using Post Method from the view to the controller ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a element that called scanned-result that is having a list of barcodes, after I get all the codes I'm using the `querySelectorAll` from the elements I'm saving it in a String Array and then I send this list into the controller.
What can I do to send this array parameter `urlParameter` as a **Post Method** instead of use window.location.href to the controller?

When I start scanning the barcodes will save in `results.innerHTML`

```
function startScanning(facingMode) {
        console.log(facingMode)
        var results = document.getElementById('scanned-result');
       function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
            if (lastMessage !== qrCodeMessage) {
                lastMessage = qrCodeMessage;
                ++codesFound;

               results.innerHTML += `<div> ${qrCodeMessage}</div>`;
               

            }
        }
```

When stop scanning I'm going to get the array looking by the element scanned-result sending the array to the controller, Here is when I'm stuck I'm not sure what I need to change to make it to send the parameter as a Post Method

```
 function stopScanning() {

          
        var QRCodeval = document.querySelectorAll("#scanned-result>div");
        var arr = [];
        QRCodeval.forEach((el) => arr.push(el.innerHTML));

        let urlParams = arr.map((val) => {
            return `arr=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`
        }).join('&');

     window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ReceivedFromBarCode", "PurchaseOrder")?arr" + urlParams;
}
```

In the View is going to appear the values on id="scanned-result"

```
<div class="modal-footer">
 <div id="scanned-result""> 
 </div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ReceivedFromBarCode(string[] arr)

        {
            try
            {
                }
                return RedirectToAction($"Details");
            }
            catch (VTHIS.CommunicationException cex)
            {
                throw cex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you want to post, you'll need to use ajax, which involves using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). When using those APIs you'll need to decide what encoding to use, and that will determine how to get the data into the post body.

Comment: Can I do it without using Ajax? or using a Form Action?

Comment: Sure, you'll need a `<form action="@Url.Action("ReceivedFromBarCode", "PurchaseOrder")">` element, and you'll need an element or multiple elements to hold the data you're going to post. I suggested ajax because you're already doing things via JavaScript, but you could submit the form via JavaScript as well.

Comment: That is great thank you yes my problem is that I'm kind of stuck so if you see the Id in my modal in the view I have an ID scanned-results so every time than I'm scanning a qrcode is showing  there on the screen so I'm building it dynamically what I need to create to save it as an array in a form that is where I'm a little confusing how to do it

Comment: So I need help more in HTML part because if I do a form I'm not having inputs so I'm doing it dynamically how can I submit this values?

Comment: ``results.innerHTML += `<div> ${qrCodeMessage}</div>`;`` => ``results.innerHTML += `<input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="${qrCodeMessage}">`;`` That will add the appropriate form elements to your form.